# Random number generator in a 2p2 Network

Tags: random-number-generator, pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-function, verifiability

for my thesis I am trying to develop a system where nodes from a peer to peer network agree in generate a random number every tot seconds.

I am stocked in this problem since almost 1 week anyone can help me with some great ideas not to hard to implement?

I already found this *"Scalable Bias-Resistant Distributed Randomness"* http://www.ieee-security.org/TC/SP2017/papers/413.pdf but implement this in python I think will be hard.

more about the project:
I will use this system in my own private bloackchain.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider an implementation based on a secret sharing scheme. In this approach all parties locally generate a random number and generate shares of it which are distributed across the network. Each party then locally sums all their shares of the individual random values to yield a uniform random value which is guaranteed random given that at least one peer is honest, and is unknown to all parties. They can then cooperate to reveal the resulting value. Shamir's secret sharing scheme, or additive secret sharing both could be good methods to achieve this desired functionality. [Shamir's paper](https://cs.jhu.edu/~sdoshi/crypto/papers/shamirturing.pdf)

Comment: Looks a good starting point but I am thinking about a possible  scalability problem could I still apply this is a very big peer to peer network?

Comment: Very large peer networks will likely strain this approach as broadcasting messages or all-to-all message exchanges are required for this approach. The idea underlying it may afford some kernel for a method to proceed, however. Additionally, if the set of peers is not too large, this can work very well.

Comment: How many nodes the network could have for you?

Comment: It could have arbitrarily many, but the communication costs go up with each addition. Specifically, for values of l bits, and n parties, the communication costs will be O(ln^2). You've got to decide if that is going to be too great for your application and the number of peers.

Comment: Algorand = scalability https://blog.acolyer.org/2017/11/21/algorand-scaling-byzantine-agreements-for-cryptocurrencies/